# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, file-not-found

Im trying to build google chrome extension.
Below is my manifest file; I searched every where and took every step to resolve  **chrome-extension://ijkjkkkinepajpigeijodppknjgdooef/popup.html** 
 **Error code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"name": "Game Extension",
"version": "1.2.0",
"description": "Just for Fun",
"icons": {
"256": "img/icon.png"
},
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"identity",
"http://*/*", 
"https://*/*"
],
"oauth2": {

"client_id": "232343423423PrivateClientKey",
"scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"] 
}
}
```

I have done everything , but issue is still there. Also,inside Extension

folder(**%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data**),like other extensions my extension has no folder.

Please let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: Any errors in background page?

Answer (score 6):

Presumably, you are loading an unpacked extension.

Suppose you have a folder where your `manifest.json` file is. For the sake of an example, `C:\Development\MyTestExtension`

Then this folder becomes the root for the extension (in your case, `chrome-extension://ijkjkkkinepajpigeijodppknjgdooef/`)

So, if you declare `popup.html` as your, well, popup, Chrome will look for `C:\Development\MyTestExtension\popup.html`. Make sure this is exactly how that file is named: on Windows, file extensions are hidden by default and it's very easy to save a file as, say, `popup.html.txt` and not see the `.txt` part.

As for a folder in the profile: it's only for *packaged* extensions that you download and install, not development *unpacked* versions.

Comment: I'm in developer mode, i use **Load unpacked Extension** option, and previously it was working fine, but suddenly it stopped.
For an Experimental purpose, i created another html page, on onload event of that page i open new tab using javascript ,gave url of  popup,html.  _Same Error_  .  I'm not able understand what is going  wrong

Comment: Hmmm... no, that's not it.... mine is packaged and it's still doing this occasionally.... really irritating

Comment: I think I might be onto something... checking to see if setTimeout is causing the issue. The docs say that setTimeout isn't supported in a background script, and to use alarms instead. Hopefully this will fix the issue.